# How do I make a vector exactly reach a line?

Tags: mathematics, algorithm, vector

Let's say a vector starts at Point P and points in the direction of v. How do I make sure that this vector exactly reaches the line? Its end should be exactly on the line, and not cross it.

[image: Illustration of a vector exactly meeting a line]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should calculate the intersection point (IP) between the two lines.

```
      (X - Ax)     (Y - Ay)
EQ1 = --------  =  --------   =>   (X-Ax) * (By-Ay) - (Y - Ay) * (Bx - Ax) = 0;
      (Bx - Ax)    (By - Ay)

      (X - Px)     (Y - Py)
EQ2 = --------  =  --------   =>   (X-Px) * (Vx) - (Y - Py) * (Vy) = 0;
         (Vx)        (Vy)
```

Solve the two equations and you get IP (X,Y).

Maybe you'd need to check that IP is between A and B... before continue...

Then you build a new line with this equation:

```
  (P + V) = P + t*(IP-P)   => t = V / (IP - P) 

   t = (IP.X-P.X != 0) 
        ? (V.X / (IP.X - P.X)) 
        : (V.Y / (IP.Y - P.Y));

  if t>1 then (P+V) has overpassed the line
```

EDIT:

[image]

Remember:

```
1) You have to calculate IP. the intersection point
2) You should check that IP is between A and B
3) You had the vector V, and now have the vector (IP-P),
4) You can choose betwwen two options:
   a) Now you can compare the vector lenghts to now if V is greater that (IP-P)
   b) Calculate t as I described before...
           if t==0 => V=(0,0);  
           if t=1 => V=(IP-P)
           if (t>0 && t<1) length(V) < length(IP-P)
           if (t>1) length(V) > length(IP-P)
```

[image]

Comment: It looks nice. Is it possible that to include a solved example. It will very helpful

Comment: beat me to it.. +1

Comment: @Blau, Please help. I have not understand your formula. P + t*(IP-P). I think it is a vector and you are checking it as scaler

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://alienryderflex.com/intersect/

Comment: @RoyT. It did'nt help.

Comment: You have to divide it in parametric forms... (P.X + V.X) = P.X + t *(IP.X-P.X), (P.Y + V.Y) = P.Y + t *(IP.Y-P.Y), to calculate "t" choose one of them having in count that the factor multiplying to "t" must be not equal to 0.

Comment: @Blau, Can you please include a very simple example. I don't get,'Choose one of them ......'

Comment: t = (IP.X-P.X != 0) ? (V.X / (IP.X - P.X)) : (V.Y / (IP.Y - P.Y));

Comment: @Blau, t is always coming less than 0. I think you are assuming that P + V is either across the line or outside or on the line. But you are not considering, P + nTimes * V. In your case nTimes is always 1.

Comment: @Blau, Sorry, t is not less than 0. It is less than 1. The only problem is that, P+ nTimes * V. I don't know how much nTimes is. It may be 1(as in your case).

Comment: @Blau, please help me, I can't extend the vector. Vector is fixed. I can only change the starting Point P.

Comment: t=0 =>  P + 0*(IP-P) = P

Comment: t=1 => P + 1 * (IP-P) = P + IP - P = IP

Comment: t>1 => P+ t*(IP-P) is overpassed the line

Comment: t>0 && t<1  then P+V is between P and IP

Comment: Thanks Blau. I will check this when I get to work and let you know. Really appreciate your work. Please keep in mind that, P + V may be far behind P + (IP - P). So, P + n * V may be on the line or outside the line.

Comment: Thanks @Blau, it works. I am very thank-full to you. I hope your explanation will also help other guys.

Answer (score 2):

### You should:

1. Find an (X, Y) point of intersection of your line and a support line for the vector.
2. Extend your vector by the distance from its end to than point you've found.

#### Example:

1. Find the (X, Y) point: solve the

   `(X - Ax) * (By - Ay) - (Y - Ay) * (Bx - Ax) = 0`

   and

   `(X - Px) * Vx - (Y - Py) * Vy = 0`

   equations.
2. Your new vector will be **Your old vector** (both components) plus **YVN** * **Dist**;

   - where **YVN** is **Your old vector** normalized (one-unit length);
   - where **Dist** is distance between **N** and **V**;
   - where **N** is your newfound<strike>land</strike> **point**.

Comment: Is it possible that you please with an example. Like Blau demostrate with an example.

Comment: @user960567 okay.

Comment: I can't extend the vector. Vector is fixed. I can only change the starting Point P.

Comment: @user960567 okay now?

Comment: I said that I cannot change vector

Comment: The drawing in your question clearly extends the vector, in stead of moving the starting point. If that's not what you want, your drawing is horribly misleading.

Comment: @Paul-Jan, Sorry for that

Comment: @user960567 if the answer answers your question, do not forget to accept it as an answer.

Comment: I think Blau answer is more suited for me. BTW, thank u very much for your help.